# grid view filtered data

Tags: c#, gridview

I am interested in getting all the data a user sees in a grid view, after he applies some filters. For example, the original grid's datasource contains 10 records, but the user apply a filter after which only 5 are still being displayed, I want to take those 5 and put them in a list. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: That depends on how you filter the GridView. Did you write the routines for that?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you provide some example code.  What kind of filters?  How are they being applied?  Etc.

Comment: Base on how I understood your question. How about using a 'LIMIT' in your select query? Or maybe you can show us some example code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your grid is bound a some collection, then on postback, you can grab the datasource of the gridview, apply your filters, and save it to a new collection.

Something like:

```
var datasource = yourGridView.DataSource as List<someType>;
var filteredResults = datasource.Where( ... ); // apply your filters inside the Where
```

Obviously, replace the example variable names / types with what you're using in your code.

Comment: I should point out that I interpreted your question as more of "how do I act on the collection that a gridview is bound to", rather than "how do I apply filters to a collection".  If you were asking the latter, then please provide a little more insight and some code, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a nice little example of a kind of built in way to filter grid views:

```
protected void btnSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConn");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CustomerTable WHERE NumberOfCustomer = @NumberOfCustomer";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NumberOfCustomer", TextBox1.Text);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And then to bind the datasource to a list:

```
protected void bindToList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var datasource = GridView1.DataSource as List<Customers>;

    if ( !IsPostBack )
    {
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddl.DataValueField = "Id";
        ddl.DataSource = datasource;
        ddl.DataBind();

        ddl.SelectedValue = list.Find( o => o.Selected == true ).Id.ToString();
    }
}
```